# How to display lists of strings in array for one UILabel on Storyboard like tablecell (swift)

Tags: swift

```
var comments: [String] = ["Good", "Great","Excellent","Cool"]
```

I would like to show comments within one UILabel (like tablecell), but I'm not sure it's possible. If possible, how can I achieve this.

I want to use UILabel as space for comments column.

[example of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpD8x.png)

Comment: Can you add more code you have tried with and, if possible, add more info of what you are trying to achieve, as it is not totally clear

Comment: @RITA,according to mine understanding i have comment the answer below.if this is not what you wanted please let me know.

Comment: Feels like you want these four keywords to sit in one table cell, but still different control? perhaps four buttons for the user to click?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add the array of those Strings to the single label then you can follow this approach:

```
    import UIKit
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var lblDynamic: UILabel!
        let stringsArray = ["Good", "Great","Excellent","Cool"]
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            lblDynamic.text = stringsArray.joinWithSeparator("\n")
            lblDynamic.numberOfLines = self.stringsArray.count + 1
            lblDynamic.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It really helps. Thanks so much!!

Comment: if it helped then would you mind accepting the answer, :) :)